# Как создать дату в таком формате dd.mm.yyyy в hh:mm?

Tags: javascript, дата, datetime

Приходит вот такая дата 2021-03-02T13:21:13+05:00, как ее преобразовать в "02.03.2021 в 13:21"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Получение даты из строки

Все современные браузеры, включая IE9+, понимают даты в упрощённом формате `ISO 8601 Extended`(`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`).

Вы можете его распарсить и получить временную метку:

```
var timestamp = Date.parse("2021-03-02T13:21:13+05:00");
```

потом, вы можете прокинуть в дату эту временную метку, если надо

```
date.setTime(timestamp);
```

А можете и напрямую вкинуть ее в конструктор Date

```
var date = new Date("2021-03-02T13:21:13+05:00");
```

> **Замечание:**
> Стоит отметить что Ваша дата содержит и смещение временной зоны.
> JavaScript распознает ее, но при запросе часов вернет вам соответсвующее значение из ВАШЕЙ часовой зоны.
> Поэтому, если Ваша часовая зона отличается от `+05` не удивляйтесь, отличающимся часам.

#### Кастомный формат даты

Для встроенных в локали форматов даты имеются методы `toLocaleDateString()`

Для кастомных же форматов приходится обходиться вручную или использовать стороние библиотеки.

##### Самый простой способ - решение в лоб

Можно просто взять все компоненты даты и сформировать из них строку

```js
// получаем дату
var date = new Date("2021-03-02T13:21:13+05:00");

// функция добавляющая ведущий ноль
function leadingZero(token) {
    return ("0" + token).slice(-2)
}

var year = date.getFullYear(),
    month = leadingZero(date.getMonth() + 1), // подсчет начинается с 0, поэтому увеличим на 1
    day = leadingZero(date.getDate()),
    hours = leadingZero(date.getHours()),
    minutes = leadingZero(date.getMinutes()),
    seconds = leadingZero(date.getSeconds())

var result = `${day}.${month}.${year} в ${hours}:${minutes}`;
console.log(result);
```

ну и напоследок:

#### Самое верное решение - не изобретать велосипед

И использовать имеющиеся библиотеки, например https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

В JS из коробки не предусмотрена форматирование даты. Можно воспользоваться библиотекой moment (https://momentjs.com/) или отформатировать в ручную.

```js
let now = new Date();
let datestr = ("0"+now.getDay()).substr(-2) + "."
 + ("0"+(0+now.getMonth())).substr(-2) + "."
 + now.getFullYear() + " в "
 + now.getHours() + ":" + ("0"+now.getMinutes()).substr(-2)

// datestr == '02.08.2022 в 8:54'
```